# Identifying wrong raters of items

Tags: statistics, recommendation-engine, survey, pattern-recognition, rating-system

I coded a program in which people rate different products. Per rating people get a bonus point. The more bonus points people get the more reputation they get. But my issue that people sometimes give ratings not to rate but just to earn bonus points. Is there a mathematical solution to identify fake raters?

Comment: I think `math` is not the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Search for "shilling recommender systems" in Google Scholar or elsewhere. There has been a decent amount of scholarly work identifying bad actors in recommender systems. Generally there's a focus on preventing robot actions (which doesn't seem to be your concern) as well as finding humans who rate differently than the norm (i.e., rating distributions, time-of-rating distributions).

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=shilling+recommender+systems